# SVA for handshake

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

i am trying to write a SVA assertion for a handshake procedure.

In my searches I have found the following:

```
property p_handshake(clk,req,ack);
@(posedge clk)
req |=> !req [*1:max] ##0 ack;
endproperty
assert property(p_handshake(clock,valid,done));
```

However, my "done" signal is allowed to come many cycles after the valid cycle goes high. How do you make this statement ensure that "done" is asserted at *any* point after valid is asserted, without valid being deasserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$rose(req) |=> req[*1:$] ##0 ack;
```

`$rose` will start the assertion on the rising edge of `req`. `[*1:$]` means the left hand side must be true for a range of 1 to unlimited clocks. You could use `[+]` which is equivalent to `[*1:$]`.

Some other styles of writing the checker would be:

```
$rose(req) |-> req[*1:$] ##1 (ack && req);
$rose(req) |-> ##1 req throughout ack[->1];
```

Comment: Interesting point here is that you are (correctly) using `$rose()` for the enabling condition. The reason you do that, and not just `req |-> ...` is so that you don't spawn a assertion thread every cycle that `req` is high, only the first. It's a big performance win.

Answer (score 0):

don't you also need an SVA to ensure that when valid $rose's, the done is not already asserted?
If you do, then pls consider this SVA-
$rose(valid) |-> ~done ##1 $stable(~done) [*949:950] ##[1:$] done;

The above requires done to be non-asserted for a period followed by assertion sometime in the future.